# How to navigate to Record page on creating Account Record using Screen Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, automated-process, flowscreen

I have Screen Component Which captures Account Records on creating the Account Records user should be navigating to the record detail page . How can this be achieved using flows or automation . We can  create a button and  use navigation Mixin but i am looking if we can it achieve using flows or any automated process

```
// Navigate to View Account Page
    navigateToViewAccountPage() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.recordId,
                objectApiName: 'Account',
                actionName: 'view'
            },
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can leverage some of the workaround:-

1. A LWC component placed on the screen flow which has value onchange handler which triggers the navigation to record. Basically you will have **@api getter** property which has setter as well to trigger the navigation, this property will be set from flow when record is created and record id is generated. A sample example of value onchange handler in lwc is here:- [VALUE CHANGE HANDLER IN LIGHTNING WEB COMPONENT WHEN PARENT PASSES VALUE TO CHILD](https://salesforcediaries.com/2020/06/15/value-change-handler-in-lightning-web-component-when-parent-passes-value-to-child/)
2. You can use this as well - [Navigate Everywhere – Flow Action](https://unofficialsf.com/navigate-everywhere-flow-action/), don't forget to read the considerations mentioned there